# django Не открывается страница админки

Tags: django, django-admin

Изучаю django по книге Дронов В. А., "Практика создания веб сайтов". Успешно прошел первую часть - все люкс, все ясно и все работает... вот только не открывается админка. Не могу понять где накосячил.

**Вот что выдает browser**
[image: browser выдает ошибку]

**samplesite\urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('bboard.urls')),
    path('admin', admin.site.urls)
```

**bboard\urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import index, by_rubric, BdCreateView


urlpatterns = [
    path('add/', BdCreateView.as_view(), name='add'),
    path('<int:rubric_id>/', by_rubric, name='by_rubric'),
    path('', index, name='index')
]
```

Comment: Чтобы избежать закрытия вопроса, настоятельно рекомендую вам добавлять код текстом, а не картинками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

admin URL - адрес должен быть первым:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'', include('nw.urls', namespace='posts')),
```

]
В противном случае оно будет перехвачено другим соответствующим регулярным выражением в вашем приложении сообщений urlpatterns, а именно:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
```

Как правило, всегда размещайте адрес администратора в верхней части страницы проекта.urlpatterns

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо за правильную мысль. Все заработало, хотя и с некоторыми изменениями.